# Support CursorLoader with EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-cursorloader

I am using a support CursorLoader to load Contacts.

When using an API larger than 21, I call

```
loader.setUri(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.Data.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX, "true").build());
```

Meaning I will get an index of the contacts' first letters.

Upon loading, I receive this crash:

```
Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.BaseBundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.android.providers.contacts.FastScrollingIndexCache.put(FastScrollingIndexCache.java:237)
at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.bundleFastScrollingIndexExtras(ContactsProvider2.java:8320)
at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.queryLocal(ContactsProvider2.java:7803)
at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.queryDirectoryIfNecessary(ContactsProvider2.java:6083)
at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:6065)
at com.android.providers.contacts.SemcContactsProvider2.query(SemcContactsProvider2.java:550)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:247)
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
```

As well as

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.BaseBundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1689)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:537)
at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:80)
at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:61)
at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:39)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:306)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:59)
at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:47)
at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Can anyone help out?

**UPDATE**

The same occurs when using the ContractsData.CommonDataKinds.Phone view, even although the column is exposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs example code it looks like they're appending this parameter to `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` not `Data.CONTENT_URI` like you do.

```
Uri uri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
          .appendQueryParameter(Contacts.EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX, "true")
          .build();
```

You said you're using `CursorLoader` to load `Contacts`, then you might want to query on the `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` table for that, the `Data.CONTENT_URI` is meant for getting specific details (emails, phones, etc.) on contacts, not basic info like name or pic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, it is not exactly what I am looking for since I am looking to use Data.CONTENT_URI and Phone.CONTENT_URI, which have their own EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX. My question is why to expose this extra if it is not used.

Comment: in the ContactsContract.Data docs, they do mention this extra, however, if you click on it to see the code example, it uses `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` not `Data.CONTENT_URI`.
It makes sense too, because `EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX` only makes sense in Contacts contexts, not Data, you never see A-Z scrollers in lists that show all EMAILS and PHONES on the phone. You only see those scrollers for contacts

Comment: I guess it does make sense. Just odd to me that they expose a reference if it is not used.
Thanks for your help!